# Forcing Linux (Ubuntu 18.04) to deallocate some cache prior to high priority job

Tags: linux, performance

I have a server that periodically has to do a high priority job as quickly as possible. I know before hand when the job will need to run. I want to tell Linux to do all it's housekeeping a few seconds prior to the job running.

Is there a way to do this?

From reading online I can see that Linux periodically (when the page cache is all used) deallocates parts of the page cache. Is there a way to know how much of the page cache is used? Is there a way to tell Linux to do that work immediately rather than letting it decide when it will do that?

Is there other house keeping that might interfere with my high priority task

Comment: Are you having an actual performance problem? This smells a lot like premature optimization.

Comment: Cache is almost always dropped in favour of swap-backed (typical memory allocation) memory. There seems no point to doing this or this suggestion seems a means to an end. Do you have some specific examples of the kind of issues you're trying to avoid going forward?

Comment: fair comments... yea, i'm shooting in the dark.